# Cordova Plugin Asynchronous Hooks not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, asynchronous

I've been writing a Cordova plugin, following [this documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html). I'm able to install the plugin without issues, however, when calling some asynchronous code in my hook, that code will never run (or at least thats my suspicion). I've tested the following code:

In my `plugin.xml` i've defined the following hook:

```
<hook type="after_run" src="lib/after-run.js" />
```

My `after-run.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = function () {
  console.log('After run!')

  function timeout() {
    console.log('Timeout!')

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('Hello World!')
      timeout()
    }, 1000)
  }

  timeout()
}
```

When running `cordova run`, i get the following output:

```
$ cordova run

... (platform building etc) ...

After run!
Timeout!
io.cordova.hellocordova: 68915
logPath: /Users/niklas/temp/temp/sampleApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

I was, however, *expecting* to get something like this:

```
$ cordova run

... (platform building etc) ...

After Run!
Timeout!
Hello World!
Timeout!
Hello World!
Timeout!
Hello World!

...
```

So my question is: why is this? And how do i get the wanted behaviour? i.e. how do I specify when my hook is finished, instead of it just being "cut off".

---

**Notes:**

1. I'm testing this with a clean Cordova project using the iOS platform
   and no other plugins.
2. There's no log available at the location specified in the console output.
3. When testing `after-run.js` using node, I get the expected output.
4. I've also tried the 'promise' approach specified [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html#script-interface), with similar results to my own test above.

Comment: You must use a promise to prevent the child process from terminating before your code inside the timeout has executed. It works as-is if you run directly with node because it's not being spawned as a child process. But when your hook script is executed by the Cordova CLI, it's as a child process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already tried the promise-approach specified here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html#script-interface. However, this yielded the same result, i.e. the asynchronous code not running. Are you able to produce a working example using promises?

Comment: I [use the promise method](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config/blob/master/hooks/applyCustomConfig.js#L1052) in the [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin which works fine.

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. I got something to work. Sort of. When i use promises in the `before_run`-hook, everything seems to work. However, then doing the same code in the `after_run`-hook, my method is cut short. This is the code i used for my testing: https://gist.github.com/NiklasWebnuts/e33e986a033ee0e8832f7a93744f0be9

Comment: I had a suspicion about the `after_run` hook - it's not used very often, so I bet it doesn't get much testing.

Comment: I've posted an issue for the Cordova project. I'll keep this thread updated if/when they reply.